# SOAPUI - GROOVY storing Test case "Properties" and store them in an array

Tags: groovy, soapui

I was wondering if there is a way to store all these properties in an array (probably using some iteration) without doing a redundant task by manually type each property value and add them to an array.

**The properties:**

[image]

**Groovy script**

```
def eID = testRunner.testCase.testSteps["eKiosk details"].getPropertyValue('eKiosk_ID')
def eName = testRunner.testCase.testSteps["eKiosk details"].getPropertyValue("eKiosk_name")
def eLocation = testRunner.testCase.testSteps["eKiosk details"].getPropertyValue('eKiosk_location')
def oState = testRunner.testCase.testSteps["eKiosk details"].getPropertyValue('Operational state')
def eBankNotes = testRunner.testCase.testSteps["eKiosk details"].getPropertyValue('Bank note counter')
```

Answer (score 0):

print the value of `testRunner.testCase.testSteps["eKiosk details"].getClass()`, then google for javadoc for this class - probably you'll find an answer by yourself.

if i'm not making mistake `testRunner.testCase.testSteps["eKiosk details"].getClass()` should return class that implements [TestStep](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/5.5.0/com/eviware/soapui/model/testsuite/TestStep.html)

there is `[getProperties()][2]` methos that returns map.

```
def props = estRunner.testCase.testSteps["eKiosk details"].properties

log.info("eKiosk_ID = ${props.eKiosk_ID.value}")
```